# Control Center not closing after I open it in Deepin

Tags: linux

I recently installed Deepin Desktop Environment in Linux mint and it works great but when I open the control center I can't close it unless I open the 'APP' launcher is this normal if not could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using multiple monitors?
In my case, the default hot-corner settings didn't work, so I had to define a hot-corner on the top right for "control center. If you are using an extended desktop, the top right will be on your external monitor most likely.
Now I can open and close the control center using the hot corner